# Is it better to use onclick or to wire click handlers on page load

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have markup like this:

```
<form action="foo">
    <input name="bar" />
    <button type="button">Save</button>
</form>

<script>
    function baz() {
        // Submit form via AJAX
    }
</script>
```

Is it better to add this to the `<button>`:

```
onclick="baz()"
```

or to add this to the `<script>` (assuming jQuery):

```
$(function(){
    $('button').on('click', baz);
});
```

I've seen much ado about best practices forbidding inline javascript, and I tend to agree.  But I'm wondering if the manual wiring on document load/ready obfuscates what's going on since it removes the context of said wiring that is present when onclick="baz" is used.

Are there maintainability issues either way?  Other pros/cons to either approach?  My question at heart is what is the industry consensus on this particular aspect of using inline javascript (given that in general it's not a good coding practice)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second way is considered better

```
$(function(){
    $('button').on('click', baz);
});
```

It is referred to as [Unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) where you separate the functionality/behavior from the page structure.

Comment: I just realized another benefit of going unobtrusive, at least if you use jQuery.  If you wire things inline you get the native event object.  If you wire with jQuery, you get the benefits of jQuery's event cross-browser normalization code instead of having to re-roll your own every time you code an event handler.  To me, that seems huge.  Otherwise, if you use jQuery but wire events inline, you lop off a significant benefit of using jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

As a professional developer, I'm wholly unconvinced that the second method at all disentangles the javascript from the page structure.  They're functionally equivalent, and to add an unnecessary layer of abstraction only confuses the issue.

Functional equivalence:

- They both make assumptions about the javascript to be attached.

  - The former presumes the existence of baz()
  - The latter presumes the existence of $('button').on('click', baz);
- Neither does anything without said javascript - they;re completely broken.

More importantly, they each have their issues.  I support inline javascript, for a few reasons:

- The ability to readably pass in arguments [onClick="baz(this)"] allows you to generate more variable code without all the general unreadability that comes with javascript.
- Maintainability skyrockets.  All I have to do is find "function baz(" in my scripts, and I've started debugging, as opposed to the former, which can be attached via any method of selecting the item - IDS that may appear throughout your code, classes, and other CSS Selectors.
- I believe that as much work as can be done server side really should be.  It's easy to upgrade and bug test on your servers.  It's much, *much* harder to imagine every possible test case your client might have.  The more work your computers do, the more you control in the execution of the function.
- It saves people from the hideous temptation of dynamically generated JS.

Comment: I'd have to disagree about maintainability skyrocketing.  If you have 10 elements you have 10 places to update the onclick js, vs one place if you wire by selection.

Comment: @jinglesthula If you're the only one who touches the code, you're probably right, but in an environment where many hands are binding many functions to many pieces of code, debugging someone else's binding can be excruciating.

Comment: I think that's one reason I was originally torn between the two when I posted the question.  I can totally see the upside of readability and being 'in context' with inline click handlers for simple cases and such.  I'm not the most articulate at presenting the costs and benefits of unobtrusive over inline, but my impression is that the industry has moved that direction and has solid reasons for doing so.  Still, it would be nice to have a way to see those references as you're reading through markup if you go unobtrusive.  Tradeoffs, I guess.

Comment: I've been revisiting this topic lately, and I think another item in favor of not wiring things inline is that it avoids the necessity of polluting the global JavaScript namespace, which is another thing I've heard trumpeted emphatically more and more as time goes on.